# Make an SD card installed on PCB readable through USB

Tags: usb, spi, sd

I work on a circuit that logs data onto an SD card.

I want to know how I can read the SD card data directly from my PC using USB.

I am thinking of using a type of SPI to USB converter because there is SPI communication between the SD card and PIC32 .

Does anyone have suggestions?

(I think that I need a FTDI chip for the USB-SPI communication; and a "Level shifter"  for the adaptaion of the voltage betwen the USB PC and SD CARD)
[image]

[image]

Comment: If you already use the SPI with the PIC MCU, it will be complicated to add another component to masters the SD. Maybe use a USB-UART FTDI: SD <---SPI---> PIC <---UART---> FTDI <---USB---> USB connector.

Answer (score 8):

The cheapest solution from a hardware point of view would be to use a MCU that includes a USB interface (there are a lot of them in the PIC32MK/MZ/MX ranges), and just make the MCU responsible for all the communication to/from both the SD card and the USB interface. Implement the Mass Storage USB device class (or, alternatively, the Media Transfer Protocol class) in software on the MCU (there are a lot of examples and resources around: e.g. Microchip [AN1169](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/appnotes/01169a.pdf)), and it will allow a computer to be able to browse and read the files when connected to the board.

This solution, however, will require heavier software development. But it is both the simplest in terms of hardware architecture, and the most flexible (if you want to implement other services through the USB port, you can. If you want the MCU to forbid some operations under specific conditions, or filter/preprocess the data on the way from the SD card to the computer, you can. And any modification on these features can be made with a simple firmware update).

This software solution would definitely be the route I'd be following if I were you.

Now, if you want this to be implemented in hardware, it is still possible: you need some USB SD card reader chip (the level shifting will typically be done by this chip). There are a handful of those: Microchip USB2660, MAX14502, and lots of them from Taiwanese manufacturers: GL823U, MA8121, ... Not sure FTDI is a good choice: they have some USB to SPI bridge, but they don't directly implement the USB Mass Storage device class, so you'd need some dedicated software on the PC to be able to browse files (maybe they have a specific firmware/chip somewhere implementing mass storage but I couldn't find it).

Then you need a way to switch the SD card bus to be connected either to the card reader chip or to your MCU. Some 1:2 analog multiplexer can do the job here (better use an analog multiplexer because the SD pins can be bidirectional). Choose one that can handle the frequency required by your SD card speed.

The MAX14502 card reader chip is particularily interesting because it is supposed to act as a middle-man between the USB/SD ports and the MCU, so you can choose to bypass the MCU and go through the reader chip, or go through the MCU. In short, the above multiplexer is builtin (see datasheet page 18), and it even includes a similar multiplexer for the USB port. That will simplify the hardware in your specific case.

Comment: USB 2.0 reader chips are about 25-50 cents in volume.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need your PIC and the computer to be able to access the card simultaneously, you could drop a USB->SDIO host controller (e.g. [VUB300](http://www.saelig.com/pr/vub300.html)) and provide some sort of bus arbitration mechanism for the SD interface. E.g. when you plug in USB, the PIC resets the SD card and puts its SPI pins to Z-state to let the SDIO host controller to work with it.

This may be tricky to get to work in hardware, and more expensive. On the plus side, you don't write any software to access the SD card from PC.

Comment: Simultaneous access to a mass storage device would be a challenge from system standpoint, and would require some serious OS support. So the suggested bus switch looks as the best simple solution. +1.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an interesting idea, but is there a reason you can’t use an off the shelf USB to SD Card adapter based on a commercial IC (e.g., Alcor Micro, Genesys logic, Norelsys, others)?

Comment: I understand that the OP's idea is to access files without removing the SD card from their device.